# Runtime comparison in R: set runtime threshold

Tags: r, microbenchmark

I'm using `mcirobenchmark` for comparing runtimes of some functions and repeat this procedure for increasing input vectors. Some functions may take very long and I don't want to wait that long, so I would like to abort computations of these slow functions and instead just return `NA` as time value for these expressions. Is there a way to set a threshold so that the `microbenchmark` (or applying the  `rbenchmark` package) aborts as soon as this threshold is hit? Thanks!

In the following I present my quick and dirty work around, where I remeber if the runtime for former input was above the threshold and prevent future execution for bigger input vecotrs. `df` stores this information.
This is not quite what I'm looking for, since in general the execution time does not monotonically increase with the size of input.

```css
df <- data.frame(expr = c("foo1(x,y)",
                          "foo2(x,y)",
                          "foo3(x,y)"),
                 doit = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cond_mic <- function(expr, df, repetitions, threshold, nn){
   if(df[df$expr == expr, "doit"]){
      mic <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(eval(parse(text = expr)),
                                            times = repetitions)
      mic <- data.frame(expr = expr, times = mic$time,
                        nn=nn, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      if(median(mic$time) > threshold){
         df[df$expr == expr, "doit"] <- FALSE
      }
   }else{
      mic <- data.frame(expr = rep(expr, repetitions), times = NA, 
                        nn=nn, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   }
   return(list(mic = mic, df = df))
}

REPETITIONS <-  2
#THRESHOLD <- 60 * 10^9# 1 minute in nano seconds
#THRESHOLD <- 1 * 10^9# 1 sec in nano seconds
THRESHOLD <- 1 * 10^6# 1 millisec in nano seconds

mics <- list()
for(nn in seq(10, 100, 30)){
   
   set.seed(nn)
   x <- rnorm(nn)
   y <- rnorm(nn)
   
   for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
      tmp <- cond_mic(df$expr[i], df, REPETITIONS, THRESHOLD, nn)
      df <- tmp$df
      mics[[length(mics)+1]] <- tmp$mic
   }
}
   
mics <- do.call(rbind, mics)
```